# Does Tight Variable Packing Matter for Constant Variables?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
uint8 public constant zero = 0;
uint8 public constant treeHeight = 32;
uint64 public constant treeWidth = uint64(2 ** treeHeight);
uint public leafCount; // the number of leaves currently in the tree
```

I am trying to optimize for Gas.  Keep reading about tight variable packing and was wondering if it applies to constants as well or if I am wasting my time trying to optimize the storage slots/access for these constants.

I am finding that making the vars smaller than uint256 makes contract creation much more expensive, which only pays off if I take advantage of the fact that all the vars are now in one slot when accessing.

Then again I don't know if any of this matters for constants and if I should just have all my constants be uint256.

Any help/advice appreciated :)

Comment: Don't post a picture of code (either inline or linked), post the code directly here as text, with the proper formating.

Answer (score 1):

Packing does not matter for constant variables.

Constant variables are not in storage but inlined in the EVM bytecode with opcodes. Bytecode packing is always tight-like and not subject to the same 256-bit padding rules as storage.

I assume for most of cases of constants, `PUSHXXX` opcodes are used. However I did not confirm this.

[More here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/140629/620).

[EVM opcodes](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/opcodes/).